# no match for 'operator>>' in std::cin >>

Tags: c++, string

I seem to be having a issue with trying to get input from a user into a string. I have done this successfully before. but now it is throwing up the error here.

```
error: no match for 'operator>>' in 'std::cin >> Pat1'
```

In reference to this code here.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cctype>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

string PatConvert(string myString);

int main(){
    string Pat1[5],Pat2[5];
    cout<<"Please give the two five charter patterns";
    cin>>Pat1;//where the error occurs.
    cin>>Pat2;
    Pat1=PatConvert(Pat1);
    Pat2=PatConvert(Pat2);
    if (Pat1==Pat2){
        cout<<"The patterns match!";
        return 0;
    }else {
        cout<<"The patterns don't match!";
    }
}

string PatConvert(string myString){
    string filler[5];
    int fillerCount=1;
    for (int i=0; i<myString.length(); i++){
        for (int i2=0; i2<filler.length(); i2++){
            if (myString[i]==filler[i2])){
                break;
            }else if(myString[i]!=filler[i2]andi2==5){
                filler[fillerCount]=myString[i];
                myString[i]=fillerCount;
                return myString;
            };
        }
    }
}
```

I am wondering what is causing the issue as I have looked at other instances of this error and they seem to occur when new variable types are made without the code that lets them be "overloaded" I think it is.

But seeing as this is a string and that I have used "cin>>" before to get user input to a string I am out of ideas as what to do.

As a side note there is *a lot* more build error information (~200 lines). If it is needed I will add it but it doesn't seem related to this issue directly.

Comment: there is no >> which takes a string array.  Are you sure you want arrays of strings and not just strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `operator>>` for reading into arrays of `std::string`, you will either have to define your own or use a loop.

```
for (auto& s : Pat1)
  std::cin >> s;
```

Then again you may have not intended to define an array of strings in the first place, redefine your strings as `string Pat1, Pat2;`

Other errors include not returning a string in `PatConvert`, an extra bracket in `if (myString[i] == filler[i2]))` and this `} else if (myString[i] != filler[i2]andi2 == 5) {` should probably be `} else if ((myString[i] != filler[i2]) && (i2 == 5)) {`

Comment: I thought I had been defining the length of the string. Thank you.

Comment: @toa697 `std::string`s will keep track of their length for you.